# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception(Flutter Firsbase)

Tags: firebase, flutter

Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.

  > File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it. 
  >   Searched Location: 
  >   D:\Android\AndroidApps\studentdb\android\app\src\nullnull\debug\google-services.json
  >   D:\Android\AndroidApps\studentdb\android\app\src\debug\nullnull\google-services.json
  >   D:\Android\AndroidApps\studentdb\android\app\src\nullnull\google-services.json
  >   D:\Android\AndroidApps\studentdb\android\app\src\debug\google-services.json
  >   D:\Android\AndroidApps\studentdb\android\app\src\nullnullDebug\google-services.json
  >   D:\Android\AndroidApps\studentdb\android\app\google-services.json
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

for me i was saving the google-services file with a space before .json it's fixed now